# how to press a button to the right of the div?

Tags: html, css

My mark in html:

```
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" Text="Загрузить" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
</div>
```

My css:

```
.dwnButtonDiv {
    clear:both; 
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: float: right; didn't help

Comment: you have to apply this to button.

Comment: The div doesn't have a class dwnButtonDiv so the CSS doesn't apply to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

```
<div class="class1">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" Text="Загрузить" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
</div>

.class1{
    text-align:right;
}
.dwnButtonDiv {
    clear:both; 
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives for this.

If you want to move **all content** in a div to the right, then `text-align: right` works fine. This will move the button as well as any other content to the right.

If you want to move **only the button** to the right, leaving any other content to the left, then you should apply `float: right;` to the button itself. You should also consider using `overflow: auto;` on the wrapper div (or some type of clearfix solution) to make sure the div forms correctly with floating elements inside of it.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzw7S/) demonstrating the two ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works but try to add:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" Text="Загрузить" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" style="float:right;" />
```